# How can H2 emit light with only 2 molecular orbitals?

Tags: molecular-orbital-theory, electromagnetic-radiation, emission

I know that light is emitted when an electron is excited to a higher energy state and then decays back to its ground state, emitting a photon whose energy corresponds to the difference in energy of the two energy states.

I also learned that if a H2 molecule absorbs a photon with an energy equivalent to the energy difference between the bonding and anti-bonding orbital, then the electron will be promoted to the anti-bonding orbital, causing the bond between the H atoms to break (since there will be no stabilizing interaction).

My question is how can a H2 molecule emit light if the only possible higher energy state that the electron can go to is the anti-bonding oribtal, and that will break the bond (which doesnt release photons)? What am I missing here?

[image]

Comment: The light could be emitted when the dissociated atoms recombine, or perhaps tge electron returns to the ground state before the molecule can actually dissociate.

Comment: When an electron is raised to a higher level, that *absorbs* energy. When it **falls back** to a lower energy state, it *releases* energy.

Comment: Experiments show that there are several electronically excited states of increasing energy, each of these also has vibrational & rotational  levels from which emission can occur.

Comment: As 1s is not the only orbital in H atoms. transition to the antibonding sigma orbital is not the only option.

Comment: Gerhard Herzberg (Nobel Prize in Chemistry, 1971) literally wrote the book on the spectra of diatomic molecules: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gerhard_Herzberg. So molecular spectroscopy is complex and the little first year chemistry MO diagram is not particularly useful in this regard.